# reading the directory structure and converting it into JSON object in java

Tags: javascript, java, json, directory-structure

I am required to read the directory structure in my file system and convert it  into Json object **in java** to be further processed in javascript. What is the most appropriate way to proceed?

Comment: Why is this question tagged `java`?

Comment: Sir, I need a code in java, that's why the tag. It wasn't mentioned earlier, my bad. Now, made the necessary changes @DavidConrad

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-traverse-a-directory-structure-in-java/

Comment: Reading the directory structure part is already answered in comments, convert to json should be pease of cake. and you mention further processed in javascript, what do you mean here?

Comment: I shall be transmitting the json object to my javascript code where it will b unboxed and a tree like structure be formed at the UI @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ

Comment: We would really like to help you, but I would suggest you start with file structure from example in comment, and convert it to json tons of json example is online, and when you have a question regarding javascript back let us know, the problem right now, you have not tried any thing and you need to cover 3 question in one.

Comment: Alright sir, I shall get back to you for help on facing any difficulty. @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ I am unable to create a json type object of the given directory structure. Can you please help.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ

public static void displayIt(File node) {
        if (node.isFile() && node.getAbsoluteFile().getName().endsWith("_param.xml")) {
            System.out.println(node.getAbsoluteFile().getName());
        }

        if (node.isDirectory()) {
         System.out.println(node.getAbsoluteFile().getName());
            String[] subNote = node.list();
            for (String filename : subNote) {
                displayIt(new File(node, filename));
            }
        }
       
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently came up with a solution for the same, would like to share with you all.
Assuming the level of hierarchy is knows to us, here is the code to convert a given file structure into a JSON object.

```
public static void convert_to_JSON(File node) {
    File[] subnode = node.listFiles();
    JSONArray ja_root = new JSONArray(); //the node has 2 different directories
    JSONArray ja_pattern = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray ja_library = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray ja_category = new JSONArray();

    for (File filename : subnode) {
        if ("newfileroot".equals(filename.getName()) || "talendfileroot".equals(filename.getName())) { // String[] libraries; 
            File[] libraries = filename.listFiles();
            for (File lib : libraries) {
                File[] categories = lib.listFiles();


                for (File cat : categories) {
                    if (cat.isDirectory()) {
                        File[] patterns = cat.listFiles();

                        for (File pat : patterns) {


                            if (pat.isDirectory()) {
                                ja_pattern.add(pat.getAbsoluteFile().getName());


                            }

                        }
                        //createjson object here - put cat as key and json array as value
                        JSONObject jo2 = new JSONObject();
                        jo2.put(cat.getAbsoluteFile().getName(), ja_pattern);
                        ja_category.add(jo2);
                         ja_pattern = new JSONArray();
                    }

                }
                JSONObject jo3 = new JSONObject();
                jo3.put(lib.getAbsoluteFile().getName(), ja_category);
                ja_library.add(jo3);
                ja_category = new JSONArray();
            }
            JSONObject jo4 = new JSONObject();
            jo4.put(filename.getAbsoluteFile().getName(), ja_library);
            ja_root.add(jo4);

            ja_library = new JSONArray();
        }

    }
    JSONObject jo5 = new JSONObject();
    jo5.put(node.getAbsoluteFile().getName(), ja_root);

    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("d:\\file_structure.json")) {
        file.write(jo5.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

}